# Avoid "The source conrol provider associated..... could not be found" message in SSMS

Tags: version-control, ssms

Every time I open my *.ssmssqlproj in SSMS i get the message:

> The source control provider associated
>   with this solution could not be found.
>   The projects will be treated as not
>   under source control.Do you want to
>   permanently remove the source control
>   bindings from the projects?

Even if I press "Yes" i need getting the message. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem and solved it by following [these instructions](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/06/03/Visual-Source-Safe-Error.aspx):

> I went into Tools > Options > Source Control menu, saw that my source control provider was set to None. Once I set to use Microsoft Visual Source Safe everything was happy and good to go.
>
> [image]

Comment: Visual Studio does not allow me to choose this option, even though I've used Git before.  Something else is going on.

Comment: In my case, I just chose 'Git' even though I'm not using Git. The error message has disappeared, which is all I wanted.